# How to fix int initialization issues in a method that returns an int

Tags: java, initialization, int

Java says my return value int is not initialized.

```
public static int getRow(char r)
{
    int row;
    if (r == 0) 
            row = 0;
    if (r == 1)
            row = 1;
    if (r == 2)
            row = 2;
    if (r == 3)
            row = 3;
    if (r == 4)
            row = 4;
    if (r == 5)
            row = 5;
    if (r == 6)
            row = 6;
    if (r == 7)
            row = 7;
    if (r == 8)
            row = 8;
    if (r == 9)
            row = 9; //end if
    return row;
}
```

There is an error on the `return row`, and it says that the int `row` hasn't been initialized. This method is to convert the value of a `char` to an `int` so it can be placed in an array to create a grid game. When I initialize `row` to `0`, it doesn't hit any of the if statements and keeps the value at zero. The game is a battleship game, so the values are validated to `0-9`.

Comment: If it doesn't hit any of those it won't be able to return a value.

Comment: Why not just initialize it?

Comment: `int row` -> `int row = 0;`. This `initializes` `row`

Comment: Why not simply return `r` directly?

Comment: This should do `int row = -1;`

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I'm going to guess that this is because you're comparing a character to an integer value instead of a character value.

```
r == 3;
//is not the same as 
r == '3';
```

EDIT:

If you want to simply fix your code, otherwise (because, it was pointed out, you lack a definitive initialization), you remove one of your cases and make it your else case.

```
{
    int row;
    if (r == 0) 
            row = 0;
    else if (r == 1)
            row = 1;
    else if (r == 2)
            row = 2;
    else if (r == 3)
            row = 3;
    else if (r == 4)
            row = 4;
    else if (r == 5)
            row = 5;
    else if (r == 6)
            row = 6;
    else if (r == 7)
            row = 7;
    else if (r == 8)
            row = 8;
    else (r == 9)
            row = 9; //end if
    return row;
}
```

This is fundamentally the same as what is known as a "switch - case":

```
//char r
switch(r)    {
    case '0': row = 0;
              break;
    case '1': row = 1;
              break;
    case '2': row = 2;
              break;
    case '3': row = 3;
              break;
    case '4': row = 4;
              break;
    case '5': row = 5;
              break;
    case '6': row = 6;
              break;
    case '7': row = 7;
              break;
    case '8': row = 8
              break;
    default: row = 9; 
}
return row;
```

Java's compiler is smart enough to find that there is at least one instance where it should have been initialized and move forward.

It can handle some more complex cases, but if... else... should always pass.

In the context of battleship, your range of inputs is '0' - '9', so you can assume that if you ever give it anything else that it's garbage input.

However, be mindful, this isn't necessarily the best solution, just the most obvious.  Review the other answers here for more insight.

A big part of things you're likely to do in the future will relate to working with characters or strings and extracting data, like you are doing here.

```
//char r
return Integer.parseInt(r +""); //+"" converts 'r' to "r"
//or, as mentioned below
return Character.getNumericValue(r); 
//works for things like roman numerals     
//but also will always return SOME value.
//Be aware of this, because you may not expect to get an int for 'a'
```

Will either return an integer, or throw a NumberFormatException, with no further checking.

Comment: This is not the cause of the error.  You can compare an integer to a char.

Comment: Yes, but if he is passing '1' and comparing it against 0-9, it's not ever going to initialize.

Comment: Yes, but even if you add single quotes around all the numbers, the error will still remain.

Comment: True, I'll modify the solution into that.

Answer (score 2):

What if `r` is not in the range of `0 to 9`? Then uninitialized `row` will be return! Thats why you are forced to initialize `row`.

Initialize `row` with a default value, or put an `else` block.

I'm not sure, but are you looking for `Character#getNumericValue`? [Read more](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char)).

So you can just easily do that:

```
public static int getRow(char r) {
    return Character.getNumericValue(r);
}
```

But careful

> If the character does not have a numeric value, then -1 is returned. If the character has a numeric value that cannot be represented as a nonnegative integer (for example, a fractional value), then -2 is returned.

[Test live.](http://ideone.com/oTsDG2)

Comment: I think you mean `row` not `r` after the first sentence.

Comment: @tnw, yes `row` indeed, ty.

Comment: Don't forget, just as importantly:The letters A-Z in their uppercase ('\u0041' through '\u005A'), lowercase ('\u0061' through '\u007A'), and full width variant ('\uFF21' through '\uFF3A' and '\uFF41' through '\uFF5A') forms have numeric values from 10 through 35. This is independent of the Unicode specification, which does not assign numeric values to these char values.

Comment: @CaptainPrinny, you may noticed I added a link in the answer, [Read more.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char)) for OP how to use `Character#getNumericValue`. Ty for your concern.

Comment: @rakeb.void I was just putting it here.

you said "but careful" and cited the LESS LIKELY outcome

Answer (score 1):

For your code to work, initialize int row = -1; //as below

```
public static int getRow(char r)
{
int row = -1;
if (r == 0) 
        row = 0;
if (r == 1)
        row = 1;
if (r == 2)
        row = 2;
if (r == 3)
        row = 3;
if (r == 4)
        row = 4;
if (r == 5)
        row = 5;
if (r == 6)
        row = 6;
if (r == 7)
        row = 7;
if (r == 8)
        row = 8;
if (r == 9)
        row = 9; //end if
return row;
}
```

return value as -1 will indicate that none of the values 0 to 9 were passed.

But here the parameter passed is char. So if you want to compare chars use single quotes '1'. i.e. if you want to see if the input is character 1.

```
public static int getRow(char r)
{
int row;
if (r == '0') 
        row = 0;
if (r == '1')
        row = 1;
if (r == '2')
        row = 2;
if (r == '3')
        row = 3;
if (r == '4')
        row = 4;
if (r == '5')
        row = 5;
if (r == '6')
        row = 6;
if (r == '7')
        row = 7;
if (r == '8')
        row = 8;
if (r == '9')
        row = 9; //end if
return row;
}
```

In your code the characters being compared are character corresponding to ASCII 0 to 9.
Assuming that you want to return same int passed as a char, you can deal this without any if. Just return r - 48; or return r - '0'; as 48 is ASCII value of 0;

```
public static int getRow(char r)
{
    return r - 48;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that none of the `if` statements were `true`.

If you add an `else` and set the value of `row` in the `else` block, the compiler will detect that there are no code paths that result in an uninitialized value of `row` and the failure will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Making the assumption that you are expecting the a character that's in the range from '0' to '9', then this code will give you the result you are trying to produce above:

```
 public static int getRow(char r){
      return r - '0';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared `int row;` but you did not assign any value to it.

When your `r` is not in `['0' - '9']`, `row` will not have any value, because you did not assign any value to it. That is why you have to initialize `row`.

You can simplify your function further :

```
public static int getRow(char r)
{
  if( r >= '0' && r <= '9')
    return r - '0';
  else
    return -1; // or any other value according to your logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `row` will not have a value if all of the `if` statements are false.  That is the cause of your error.

Second, the "structure" of this method, IMO, is too monotonous and can be cleaned up.  Let's consider -1 to be the sentinel value.

```
public static int getRow(char r)
{
    int row = -1;
    if ('0' <= r && r <= '9') {
        row = r - '0';
    }
    return row;
}
```

Even shorter/cleaner with ternary operators and without a local variable:

```
public static int getRow(char r) {
    return ('0' <= r && r <= '9') ? r - '0' : -1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line of code `int row;` **declares** an integer variable called `row`. To **initialize** your `row` variable, you need to give it a value. If your character `r` is not between 0 and 9, your `row` variable will never have a value assigned to it.

You can **declare** and **initialize** your row variable in the same line, as such:

```
int row = 0;
```

However, Java has a built in method to do this conversion for you, so you don't need to write your own method to do it. Instead of creating your `getRow(char r)` method, you could simply call the built in method, `Character.getNumericValue(char r)`.

Answer (score 0):

If none of your if statements wouldn't be true then what would be the return value ? You can either initialized your "row" variable to something because local variable are not like instance variables, they need to be initialized with something because they don't have a thing called a default value.

```
public static int getRow(char r)
{
    int row=-1;
    if (r == 0) 
            row = 0;
    if (r == 1)
            row = 1;
    if (r == 2)
            row = 2;
    if (r == 3)
            row = 3;
    if (r == 4)
            row = 4;
    if (r == 5)
            row = 5;
    if (r == 6)
            row = 6;
    if (r == 7)
            row = 7;
    if (r == 8)
            row = 8;
    if (r == 9)
            row = 9; //end if
    return row;
}
```

so once you initialize your variables like above, if none of your if statements evaluate true then it returns -1

Also use a switch statement instead of these bunch of if statements.it will be much clear and best practice.